# How to enable ctrl-alt-backspace using console?

Tags: 64-bit, ubuntu-10.04, console, xorg, kill

How do I enable ctrl-alt-backspace using console? I have problems with X.org and often server gets stuck with black screen. I'm trying to solve this issue, but I can't find a way to kill X. ctrl-alt-F(n) does not switch to a terminal.

Comment: `Ctrl+Alt+Backspace` is deprecated, use `Alt+Print+K` instead. You could also try `kilall X`.

Comment: I'll try with Alt+Print+K. Unfortunately, my problem is that I don't have terminal access when I start X so I can't use  kilall X .

Comment: @Bobby It's working. Post this as an answer, so I can tick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl+Alt+Backspace` is deprecated, use the [Magic SysRq Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) for restarting X instead, which is `Alt+Print+K`.

Alternately, if you can switch to the tty consoles, you could try to use `sudo killall X` for killing off X.

*Sidenote:* Be aware that the `killall` command kills all processes with the given name *only under Linux*. Under BSD f.e., it will kill **all** processes...which is a rather bad thing to do.